# What's the latest version of Angular as configured by Angular CLI that uses a version of webpack < 5?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Can anyone tell me the latest version of Angular that uses a 4.x version of webpack, as created using Angular CLI?

I'm trying to put together my first simple Angular app, and I've been spinning my wheels for days trying to deal with the webpack 5 problem.  It's more important to me at this point to get back to actually working on app code and not environment configuration that should have been taken care of by Angular CLI.  I know it's being worked on, and I'm not trying to dis the CLI.  I think it's great.  I've used it for trivial learning apps previously, and I'd like to be able to continue using it on the app I'm working on now, which is my first Angular database app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v12.0.0/package.json), the `12.0.0` version updated its webpack dependency to >5.*. So the latest stable version that uses Webpack 4.x is the [11.2.19](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/11.2.19/package.json). You can see the version at line 237.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jacopo!!!